# Ignore missing types during deserialization of list

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

When deserializing a list with `TypeNameHandling.All`, if a type namespace for one of the items is missing (deleted after serialization), it will cause a `Error resolving type specified in JSON` error.
I wish to ignore these items instead, leaving the rest behind.

`Error = (sender, args) => { args.ErrorContext.Handled = true; }` in `JsonSerializerSettings` does what I'm looking for, but will capture ALL errors of course.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this, maybe via a serializer setting I've missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following properties of [`ErrorContext`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ErrorEventArgs.htm) inside a [`SerializationErrorCallback`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_SerializationErrorCallback.htm) to restrict the types of errors to be handled and ignored:

- [`ErrorEventArgs.ErrorContext.OriginalObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ErrorContext_OriginalObject.htm): this *gets the original object that caused the error.*  When list item cannot be constructucted due to an invalid type name, the `OriginalObject` will be the list itself.

  With this property, you could check to see whether `OriginalObject` is an `IList<T>` for some `T`.
- [`ErrorEventArgs.CurrentObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ErrorEventArgs_CurrentObject.htm).  Gets *the current object the error event is being raised against.*  Exceptions bubble up the serialization call stack and objects at each level can attempt to handle the error.

  You will want to handle it at the lowest level, when `CurrentObject == ErrorContext.OriginalObject`.
- [`ErrorEventArgs.ErrorContext.Error`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ErrorContext_Error.htm) - gets the actual exception thrown.  You will want to handle only exceptions thrown by the [serialization binder](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Binder.htm).

Now, how to detect and trap only those exceptions due to failed type name binding?  As it turns out, Json.NET's [`DefaultSerializationBinder`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultSerializationBinder.cs) throws a `JsonSerializationException` when a type cannot be loaded.  However, the same exception can be thrown in many other situations, including a malformed JSON file.  So, introduce an [`ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder.htm) [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that catches and traps exceptions from the default JSON binder and packages them into a specific exception type:

```
public class JsonSerializationBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    readonly ISerializationBinder binder;

    public JsonSerializationBinder(ISerializationBinder binder)
    {
        if (binder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.binder = binder;
    }

    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        try
        {
            return binder.BindToType(assemblyName, typeName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationBinderException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        binder.BindToName(serializedType, out assemblyName, out typeName);
    }
}

public class JsonSerializationBinderException : JsonSerializationException
{
    public JsonSerializationBinderException() { }

    public JsonSerializationBinderException(string message) : base(message) { }

    public JsonSerializationBinderException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

    public JsonSerializationBinderException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
}
```

Further, at some higher level in the code Json.NET packages the `JsonSerializationBinderException` inside yet another `JsonSerializationException`, so it's necessary to look through the inner exceptions for an exception of the necessary type when deciding whether to handle an exception.  The following settings does the job:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    SerializationBinder = new JsonSerializationBinder(new DefaultSerializationBinder()),
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, // Or Auto or Objects as appropriate
    Error = (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.CurrentObject == args.ErrorContext.OriginalObject
            && args.ErrorContext.Error.InnerExceptionsAndSelf().OfType<JsonSerializationBinderException>().Any()
            && args.ErrorContext.OriginalObject.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)))
        {
            args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    },
};
```

Using the extension method:

```
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Exception> InnerExceptionsAndSelf(this Exception ex)
    {
        while (ex != null)
        {
            yield return ex;
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zJhYZd).

Note that `ISerializationBinder` was introduced in Json.NET [10.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1).  In earlier versions your wrapper must inherit from [`SerializationBinder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder) and be set in [`JsonSerializerSettings.Binder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Binder.htm).

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rxNHMk).

Answer (score 0):

I've suffered similar problems which related to missingType while deserializing. And I've followed the solution CustomSerializationBinder which @dbc suggested.

But that only works when your missingType is inside List.
If you have Dictionary object that is missingType, this method will not work.

```
//This works
{
  "nodeList": [
    {
      "$type": "Leopotam.Ecs.BT.BTRuntimeAction, Assembly-CSharp",
      "taskList": []
    },
    {
      "$type": "Leopotam.Ecs.LancerGirl.BTTask.AlterResult, Assembly-CSharp", //Missing
      "alterResult": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

```
//This will not work
{
  "nodeDic": {
    "0": {
      "$type": "Leopotam.Ecs.BT.BTRuntimeSequence, Assembly-CSharp",
      "id": 0
    },
    "1": {
      "$type": "Leopotam.Ecs.BT.BTRuntimeAction, Assembly-CSharp", // Missing
      "taskList": []
    }
  }
}
```

If you have a missing type inside dictionary in this case BTRuntimeAction, and you skip error with code 'args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;'
Then next error will occur which says "Parsing error with wrong token" cannot parse "taskList" element.
Json should ignore whole section string of missingType but it just ignores one line, and parses next line, result in error.

So... Just use list