# Best way to deserialize set of objects with TypeNameHandling when some $type are unknown

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm currently using json.net to deserialize and instantiate a set of object coming from a REST service.

This service give me many object types thus I have to use `TypeNameHandling.Objects` and a custom binder to match my assembly types.

Example of response from the service:

```
{
    "rows":[
        {
            "id":"id1",
            "doc":{
                "$type":"Car",
                "color":"blue"
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"id36",
            "doc":{
                "$type":"Dog",
                "name":"hodor"
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"id52",
            "doc":{
                "$type":"Human",
                "name":"gandalf"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Types from my assembly are :

Rows:

```
public class Rows
{
    public List<Row> rows {get; set;}
}
```

Row:

```
public class Row
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public IDocument doc {get; set;}
}
```

IDocument:

```
public class Dog : IDocument
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Car:

```
public class Car : IDocument
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string color {get; set;}
}
```

Dog:

```
public class Dog : IDocument
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
}
```

I want to deserialize this answer as a `Rows` object using the custom binder:

```
public class DocumentBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (typeName == "Dog")
            return typeof(Dog);
        else if (typeName == "Car")
            return typeof(Car);
        throw new JsonSerializationException();
    }

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = null;
        if (serializedType == typeof(Dog))
            typeName = "Dog";
        else if (serializedType == typeof(Car))
            typeName = "Car";
        else
            throw new JsonSerializationException();
    }
}
```

My problem is some of this types are unknown in my assembly, let's say `Human` in my example and I do not want to modelize a `Human`. I could do so but the REST service could be updated to add new types and I do not have any control on that service.

The only way I found to deserialize all objects from this service is:

1. convert the Rows object to `JObject` with `JObject.Parse()`
2. iterate over `rows` to deserialize objects one by one ignoring `JsonSerializationException` thrown when a `$type` is unknown.

It works but with poor performance and it needs to dump the entire HTTP answer before starting to deserialize.

In order to improve performance I would like to use `StreamReader` and `JsonTextReader` but I cannot as long as I won't find a way to tell json.net to ignore unknown `$type` and return a null value if needed.
If all types are known it works as expected with streams but as soon as one type is missing it throws `JsonSerializationException`.

In my example I'd expect `doc` to be null for the `Human` type inside a perfectly deserialized `Row` object.

Is there a way to consider unknown type as `null`? Do I need my own converter to do so?

Comment: Some details you should add to your question: (1) If everything worked the way you wanted, what is the expected behavior when an unknown $type is encountered? (2) Can you give us a [reprex] that includes the code for your binder, some models, and the JSON you are trying to deserialize which also includes the unknown $type?  This will allow us to see what you are seeing so we can try to find solutions.

Comment: 1) Do you need to re-serialize without loss of information afterwards?  2) Do you need to read the properties of unknown types into some `JObject`, or just ignore them?  3) Can you share some example JSON?

Comment: Maybe this does what you want: [Ignore missing types during deserialization of list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384608/3744182).  The accepted answer uses Json.NET's error handling to ignore objects for which the serialization binder cannot find an appropriate type.

Comment: OK, that question is much clearer.  But I think you should be able to adapt the answer from [Ignore missing types during deserialization of list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384608/3744182) by removing the check `&& args.ErrorContext.OriginalObject.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))` from the `settings.Error` delegate. Removing the check will cause any unknown object to get skipped, not just an unknown list item.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Looks like that works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/9hXXo7.  Do you need any further help?

Comment: @dbc Many thanks it works!! In my custom binder I'm using a `IDictionary<string, Type>` thus I just added a `throw new JsonSerializationBinderException($"Type '{typeName}' is unknown")` when `TryGetValue` return false.

Comment: @dbc if you want to post your answer I'll mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384608/3744182) from *[Ignore missing types during deserialization of list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39383098/3744182)* and throw a custom exception, inheriting from [`JsonSerializationException`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializationException.htm), from your custom serialization binder.  Then, handle that exception using Newtonsoft's [exception handling mechanism](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm).

Modify your binder as follows:

```
public class DocumentBinder : KnownTypesBinder
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> nameToType = new Dictionary<string, Type>
    {
        {"Dog", typeof(Dog)},
        {"Car", typeof(Car)},
    };
    public DocumentBinder() : base(nameToType) { }
}

public class KnownTypesBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, Type> nameToType;
    readonly Dictionary<Type, string> typeToName;

    public KnownTypesBinder(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> nameToType)
    {
        this.nameToType = nameToType.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
        this.typeToName = nameToType.ToDictionary(p => p.Value, p => p.Key);
    }

    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if(nameToType.TryGetValue(typeName, out var type))
            return type;
        throw new JsonSerializationBinderException(string.Format("Unknown type name {0} ({1})", typeName, assemblyName));
    }

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        if(!typeToName.TryGetValue(serializedType, out typeName))
            throw new JsonSerializationBinderException(string.Format("Unknown type {0}", serializedType));
        assemblyName = null;
    }
}

public class JsonSerializationBinderException : JsonSerializationException
{
    public JsonSerializationBinderException() { }

    public JsonSerializationBinderException(string message) : base(message) { }

    public JsonSerializationBinderException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

    public JsonSerializationBinderException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
}
```

Then initialize your `JsonSerializerSettings` as follows:

```
var deserializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    SerializationBinder = new DocumentBinder(),
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects, // Or Auto as appropriate
    Error = (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.CurrentObject == args.ErrorContext.OriginalObject
            && args.ErrorContext.Error.GetBaseException() is JsonSerializationBinderException
            )
        {
            args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    },
    // Other settings as required
};
```

With these settings you will be able to deserialize your JSON directly from a stream and skip unknown `IDocument` types without having to load and pre-process a `JToken` hierarchy.

Notes:

- Json.NET may wrap an application-thrown exception in multiple layers of exception, so [`GetBaseException()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.getbaseexception) must be used to determine whether the custom exception was thrown.
- You probably do not want to handle `JsonSerializationBinderException` when **serializing** because an exception while serializing would indicate a bug or missing type in your binder.
- By handling only your custom exception, you ensure that exceptions due to other errors are not swallowed.  E.g. a `JsonReaderException` caused by a malformed JSON file should never be swallowed because doing so may cause the `JsonTextReader` to fall into an infinite loop.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7aXvKT).